# Where are IPO curves and deltas?

Tags: graph-editor, fcurves

I'm following an old tutorial from January 2006 (Blender Art Magazine). It mentions IPO curves and delta channels. I'm now working in Blender 2.75a and I can't find any IPO curves except the Graph Editor and F-curves. Also can't find delta channels. Has it changed since version 2.40? If so, how or where to find the same functionality in new Blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online manual states that "In Blender 2.5, IPO Curves have been replaced by FCurves, however, editing these curves is essentially still the same."
https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/editors/graph/fcurves.html

I'll dig more for "deltas" info.
[edit] see this thread an BA it may help you: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?219126-Move-Existing-f-Curve-to-delta-equivalent [/edit]

I discovered there is an option "Animated Transforms to Deltas" available through the space bar command search tool, it should derive by this GSoc work http://aligorith.blogspot.it/2011/05/gsoc11-greeting-goodies.html (this is what the last comment in the above cited BA thread refers to)